# Two queries, one JSON result

Tags: sql-server, json

I have got two queries, but I just want one result:

1 Query, give me all the data of the column

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.Notificacion
 FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('notification')
```

2 Query give me all the column names

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'notificacion' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
 FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('COLUMN_NAME')
```

This way, I can make the view of the application more dynamic.

I want JSON something like this:

```json
{
  "COLUMN_NAME": [
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "ID"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "Active"
    },
        {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "date"
    },
        {
      "COLUMN_NAME": "dateUpdate"
    }
  ],
    "notification": [
    {
      "ID": 1103,
      "Active": 1016,
      "date": 0,
      "dateUpdate": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": 1103,
      "Active": 1016,
      "date": 0,
      "dateUpdate": 0
    },
        {
      "ID": 1103,
      "Active": 1016,
      "date": 0,
      "dateUpdate": 0
    }
  ]
  
}
```

Comment: does this help ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094351/how-can-i-do-a-for-json-with-2-joins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the most optimal way to skin the cat but when I need to combine different JSON results in a single output, I typically use the [`JSON_QUERY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) function.

Here is one way to apply it in your case:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAMES = JSON_QUERY(inf_sch.json_result)
, Notification = JSON_QUERY(notif  .json_result)
FROM
  (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'notificacion'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS inf_sch (json_result)
, (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Notificacion
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS notif (json_result)
FOR JSON
  PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The two derived tables are your two original queries with the `ROOT()` specifier stripped off.  They each produce a JSON output.  Each output is essentially injected into the outer level output using the `JSON_QUERY` function.  The function makes sure that its argument is injected as a JSON object rather than an `nvarchar` string representing one.

The `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option at the end of the query makes sure the top-level JSON is returned as a single object rather than an array.

Again, I understand that this may not be the best method.  Perhaps a more concise and elegant way could be achieved using the `AUTO` option of the `FOR JSON` clause.  I admit I am not very familiar with it.  Hopefully someone can come along and show both of us, as well as the rest of the audience, how to successfully use it in your scenario.